# Illuminate\Console\Command not found when developing laravel 5.8 package

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a package for Laravel 5.8. When I try to create a console command that extends Illuminate\Console\Command then "composer dump-autoload" fails with error message:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\ptest>composer dump-autoload
    Generating optimized autoload files> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
    > @php artisan package:discover --ansi

       ReflectionException  : Class TestVendor\TestPackage\TestCommand does not exist

      at C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\ptest\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:790
        786|         if ($concrete instanceof Closure) {
        787|             return $concrete($this, $this->getLastParameterOverride());
        788|         }
        789|
      > 790|         $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
        791|
        792|         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
        793|         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is
        794|         // no binding registered for the abstractions so we need to bail out.

      Exception trace:

      1   ReflectionClass::__construct("TestVendor\TestPackage\TestCommand")
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\ptest\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:790

      2   Illuminate\Container\Container::build("TestVendor\TestPackage\TestCommand")
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\ptest\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:667
```

I have tried to create the package by hand inside of C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\ptest\packages folder and I tried to use the packager https://github.com/Jeroen-G/laravel-packager but the result is identical in both cases.

TestCommand.php

```
<?php
namespace TestVendor\TestPackage;

    use Illuminate\Console\Command;

    class TestCommand extends Command {
        protected $signature = 'test:hello';
        protected $description = 'say hello';

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function handle()
        {
            $this->info("hello!");
        }
    }
```

TestServiceProvider.php

```
    <?php

    namespace TestVendor\TestPackage;

    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

    class TestServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        public function boot()
        {
            if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
                $this->bootForConsole();
            }
        }

        public function register()
        {
            $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__.'/../config/testpackage.php', 'testpackage');

            $this->app->singleton('testpackage', function ($app) {
                return new TestPackage;
            });
        }

        public function provides()
        {
            return ['testpackage'];
        }

        protected function bootForConsole()
        {
            // Registering package commands.
            $this->commands([TestCommand::class]);
        }
    }
```

When I execute the TestCommand.php file directly from command line it fails with the error message

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Console\Command' not found
```

I have checked other working packages inside "Vendor" folder and all have the same structure as my package. It seems as if autoloading does not work properly.

Comment: did you some research about your error?

Comment: When building commands, you shouldn't call the files directly. You should call them through the `artisan` command (which will boot up Laravel), just like they show in [the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan). Also, you're using the namespace `TestVendor`, have you added it to the composer.json-file so that PHP knows where to find it?

Comment: I know that commands should be invoked using artisan. Calling the command directly is a quick way to determine if there is a syntax error in the file. I've spent about 5 hours trying to fix this issue. The TestVendor namespace is in the composer.json file - this is something that the https://github.com/Jeroen-G/laravel-packager does automatically

Comment: I usually let my IDE tell me if I have any syntax errors. Anyway, have you registered the namespace `TestVendor` in your `composer.json`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The namespace already is in the autoload/psr-4 section. But the "console" folder was outside of "src" folder. Therefore it could not be discovered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? If so, will you please copy it into an answer and mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "console" folder was outside of "src" folder. Therefore it could not be discovered.

Answer (score 0):

remove vendor and node_modules folder
then run following commands

```
composer update
npm install
```

it should work fine.